# Make meta tag with reagent

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I want to render a meta tag with Reagent.

I can not find any info with Google.

[:div
     (header @company-name)]

Looks like it outputs everything into body. How to write meta tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render something into `<head>` you should do it as usual with any Reagent UI code.

```clj
(reagent.core/render [header] (.-head js/document))
```

The above will render into `<head>`.
There's also NPM package that allows rendering into `<head>` from within your app's UI tree [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet).